# how to compute chern classes of homogeneous vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm sorry for the stupid question, but..

I need to check that zero-scheme of general global section of homogeneous vector bundle over G/P (G simple algebraic group over C, say Spin, P its maximal parabolic subgroup) is non-empty. Is there an easy way to do this?

For now it seems to me that the only way to do this is to check that r-th chern class of my bundle E of rank r is nonzero. So, how do I do this?

I'm afraid I don't know any generalized schubert calculus, and not much of the intersection theory, so down-to-earth answers, or, alternatively, readable references, would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easier to compute its $T$-equivariant $r$th Chern class $c_r(E) \in H^*_T(G/P)$, and use the maps $H^*_T(G/P) \twoheadrightarrow H^\ast(G/P)$ and $H_T^*(G/P) \hookrightarrow \oplus_{W/W_P} H_T^*(pt)$.

The latter comes from restricting the equivariant Chern class to the $T$-fixed points on $G/P$ (here $T$ is a maximal torus). The ring $H_T^*(pt)$ is the symmetric algebra on the weight lattice $T^\ast$, and $c_r(E|_{wP/P}) = w\cdot ($the $r$th elementary symmetric function of the $T$-weights on the vector bundle's base fiber, over $P/P \in G/P)$.

Now, how to show that's not zero, in ordinary cohomology... well, let's pull it back to $G/B$, first, and the cohomology injects so it's enough to work up there. On $\oplus_W H_T^\ast(pt) = [$functions $f : W \rightarrow H^\ast_T(pt)]$ there is a BGG/Demazure operator $\partial_\alpha$ for each simple root $\alpha$, taking $f$ to $w \mapsto (f(w) - f(w r_\alpha))/\alpha$. (It comes from pushing the class on $G/B$ to $G/P_\alpha$, then pulling it back.)

Your $c_r$ will be nonzero iff for some sequence of $r$ simple roots $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r$, this $\partial_{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{\alpha_r} c_r$ (now necessarily a constant function on $W$) is not zero.

Not knowing your vector bundle, I can't advise you what sequence of simple roots to use, other than that it should give a reduced word in $W$. EDIT: you can choose them greedily, applying $\partial_\alpha$ and trying to stay nonzero. If you get to a point (before getting to a constant) where all $\partial_\alpha$ give zero, then your Euler class is zero.

One place this combinatorial approach to equivariant cohomology of $G/P$ is laid out is my paper with Terry Tao on the equivariant cohomology of Grassmannians.